# Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers, add info to the display-section-legend class

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

We are on Sitecore 8 using Web Forms for Marketers.

I am trying to identify how to add information to the "display-section-info" class item in a sitecore WFFM form.  Looking @ The generated code I see an element (display-section-info class) after the Field Legend, and before the starts of our fields.  I would like to put some basic information regarding the fields in this element (below has text "THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO ADD TEXT").

Here is the source from "View Source" on the browser.  Through developer tools I plugged in some info and that is exactly where I want it to go.

```
 <fieldset class="display-section-fieldset">
        <legend class="display-section-legend">1. OUTSIDE INTEREST:</legend>
            <p class="display-section-info">THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO ADD TEXT</p>

        <div class="display-section-content">

            <div class=" field-border">

        <span class=" field-title">
                <span class=" field-required">*</span>
            In the field below, list exceptions 

        </span>
```

Update1:
per Jammycans response I added a few parameters to the section but did not seem to display.  items have been published, I also confirmed on the prod DB.

**Content Editor**
[image]

**Results:**
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no field in the Form Editor to set this information, you can set it directly on the section item itself.

In the Content Editor, expand the form and select the `Form Section` item. On the section item in the `Parameters` field set the information field text you need:

```
<Information>THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO ADD TEXT</Information>
```

You can use the `Localized Parameters` field if you need to translate the text.

**EDIT:**

There is a bug in the logic on the default WFFM section view, located in `\Views\Form\EditorTemplates\SectionModel.cshtml` (for Sitecore 8 update 5 and earlier). On lines 18-21, the code reads:

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Information))
{
    <p class="@Model.CssClass display-section-info">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Information", Model.InnerItem)</p>
}
```

The first line here should read:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Information))
```

Note the **"!"**. That explains *why* you were seeing the markup previously, even though the parameter was not set. You need to update the code in the view in order to fix it.

Comment: I gave that a shot but it did not add the text to that section.  I have a few screen shots and will see if I can add to the orig email.

Comment: Which version/update of Sitecore and WFFM are you using? Have you made any changes to the default form views/cshtml files?

Comment: We are using Sitecore 8.0.2, looking into the WFFM version

Comment: I ended up adding this:`code`@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Information))
        {
            <p class="@Model.CssClass display-section-info">@Model.Information</p>
        }

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the issue was that missing "not" character so replacem not add. Did that resolve the issue? If so please upvote and mark as answer :)

Comment: It did, but I had to change the value when displaying.  I changed it to:  <p class="@Model.CssClass display-section-info">@Model.Information</p>  as the Model.InnerItem did not work.   Does that work or any other thoughts on this?

Comment: I ended up using this... <p class="@Model.CssClass display-section-info">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Parameters", Model.InnerItem)</p>

Comment: `@Model.Information` should work, since that is what the empty check is against. I don't have a 8.0.2 install locally so unable to test, but I would use the Information property since Sitecore should automatically populate that if you specify that in the Parameters field. Glad it's working nonetheless.